# iPhone 6 Plus all SMS/iMessage Disappear, but still show up in Storage

Tags: iphone

iPhone 6 Plus all SMS/iMessage Disappear, but still show up in Storage, I haven't backed up my phone for over 8 months :( and the messages mean everything to me.. It's nearly a decade worth of messages (shows how I've travelled with an iPhone since first launch).. I have never had problems of such and I want a fix.. Tried contacting Apple but they are no help.. They make me go through troubleshooting.. If it works it's worth it but it's not and I'm really upset.. I've spent over 12 hours trying for a fix and over 3 hours with Apple Telephone Support.. Do you think the guys at the store can do anything? Please HELP!! I'll actually reward the person that can help me in this dilemma.